# Default active link on page load

Tags: html, css

I have a menu that is working fine on all levels. However, one area where I am having trouble is making a link active on page load. what I want to do is to have the first link `(inbox)` active on page load. When I click another link then the active state is removed.

I Only need on page load. Many thanks

```css
.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 154px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.mainmenu,
.submenu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.mainmenu a {
  display: block;
  /*  background-color: #CCC;*/
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
}

.mainmenu a:active,
.mainmenu a:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.mainmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #444;
  color: black;
}

.mainmenu li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
  max-height: 200px;
}

.submenu a {
  background-color: #999;
}

.submenu a:hover {
  background-color: #222;
}

.submenu {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li class="inbox">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Inbox</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Sent Mail</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Received Mail</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Junk Mail</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Well I can suggest using a class instead pseudo selector `:active` and initially setting the class to the element you want to be selected. Also you will need some javascript for this solution

Comment: it is cannot be done with `html` & `css` only. you should use `javascript` at least.

Comment: `:active` only applies as long as you hold the mouse button down - so I assume you actually rather want `:focus`. Question remains, do you just want it to _look_ like that element had focus, or do you actually want to set the focus to it? Only the latter would make sense IMHO, otherwise your UI would be giving confusing and inconsistent feedback.

Comment: @CBroe The idea is when the page is loaded the `inbox` is active. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mainmenu li:first-child').addClass('active');
  $('.mainmenu li').hover(function() {
      $('.mainmenu li').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 154px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.mainmenu,
.submenu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.mainmenu a {
  display: block;
  /*  background-color: #CCC;*/
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
}

.mainmenu a:active,
.mainmenu a:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.mainmenu a:hover, .active a {
  background-color: #444;
  color: black;
}

.mainmenu li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
  max-height: 200px;
}

.submenu a {
  background-color: #999;
}

.submenu a:hover,  {
  background-color: #222;
}

.submenu {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li class="inbox">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Inbox</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Sent Mail</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Received Mail</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Junk Mail</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. However, the inbox is not active on page load. Thanks

Comment: Is `:active` classed as a class? if not where is the active class in the css. Do I just create one? Thanks

Comment: With jQuery i have added active class to list item (li) add added css for active class (.active a) in the css

Comment: If you check your snippet you will see that `inbox` is not active on page load. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add `a.firstSelected,` to your `.mainmenu` css and add the following js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mainmenu li a').click(function(e) {
    $("#first").removeClass("firstSelected");
  });
});
```

[See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/declanmcd/pgmxh102/)

What this does is it tells the first link that it is to "look like" an active link, then when any other link is clicked, to remove that style.
You can just add the class `class="firstSelected"` to any of the links you want to be the default active link instead of the first one.